# Angular App alongside jQuery Slick issue

Tags: angularjs, slick.js

I have a simple slick carousel in an Angular App, using angular-slick. Whenever I load the App for the first time (with the view that contains the slick carousel), the carousel displays correctly. However after switching to another view and returning to the carousel slick view, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: u.slick is not a function
```

the Carousel looks like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 mainContent">
    <div style="height: 50px; margin-bottom:70px;">
        <slick class="slider multiple-items slick-slider" slides-to-scroll="1" slides-to-show="3" infinite="true" speed="3000" autoplay="true" init-onload="true">
            <div ng-class="slick-slide" style="width: 187px;"><h3 class="text-center">1</h3></div>
            <div ng-cclass="slick-slide" style="width: 187px;"><h3 class="text-center">2</h3></div>
            <div ng-cclass="slick-slide" style="width: 187px;"><h3 class="text-center">3</h3></div>
            <div ng-cclass="slick-slide" style="width: 187px;"><h3 class="text-center">4</h3></div>
            <div ng-cclass="slick-slide" style="width: 187px;"><h3 class="text-center">5</h3></div>
            <div ng-cclass="slick-slide" style="width: 187px;"><h3 class="text-center">6</h3></div>
        </slick>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a reason why the (I guess) jQuery plugin gets "lost" after changing views?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you are not inadvertently loading more than one version of jQuery script. And that you are loading Angular script after the jQuery script.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I could not find any code pertaining the loading of a second jQuiery script. I implemented your second suggestion and placed the jQuery plugin before the Angular loading. Unfortunately that did not resolve the problem. I finally opted to change the angular-slick directive and use the one developed by DevMarc (https://github.com/devmark/angular-slick-carousel), which solved the problem.

Comment: Ok, glad you resolved issue :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone facing the same problem, I ended up using a different angular-slick directive, the one created by DevMarc (https://github.com/devmark/angular-slick-carousel), which solved the problem "auto-magically".